# oracle : initCap without convert all other letters in lowercase

Tags: sql, regex, database, oracle

When I use INITCAP it returns char, with the first letter of each word in uppercase, all other letters in lowercase.

so this this is result

INITCAP (oracle DB) === > Oracle Db.

However I need result as Oracle DB .

only capitalize the first character in each word without force other characters to be lower . is there away to do that ?

Comment: you have to split the text and then use initcap and later add it with other splitted text again

Comment: Please provide additional test cases. e.g. how should it convert these strings: `mcdonald`, `connor mcdonald`, `coNnor mcDonalD`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 initcap(substr('oracle DB',0,2)) + substr('oracle DB',2)
```

or

```
concat(initcap(substr('oracle DB',0,2)) , substr('oracle DB',2))
```